# linear model with Julia,error

Tags: julia, atom-editor

```
 using RDatasets
 using GLM
 housing = dataset("Ecdat", "Housing")
 plot(housing, x="LotSize", y="Price", Geom.point)
 log_housing = DataFrame(LotSize=log(housing[:,2]), Price=log(housing[:,1]))
 plot(log_housing, x="LotSize", y="Price", 
 Geom.point,Guide.xlabel("LotSize(log)"), Guide.ylabel("Price(log)"))
 lm = fit(LinearModel, Price ~ LotSize, log_housing)
 #UndefVarError: Price not defined
```

I run linear model with Julia, but I couldn't get why it has error
[This is what I do](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YBiFY.jpg)

Comment: Please include your code and errors as text, and more detailed descriptions. Have you taken a look at recent docs of GLM.jl?

Comment: I upload the code, and I will check the GLM.jl now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to estimate linear model you can use `lm` function (and your code wold actually overwrite this name), so it is better to write:

```
julia> lm_model = lm(@formula(Price ~ LotSize), log_housing)
StatsModels.DataFrameRegressionModel{GLM.LinearModel{GLM.LmResp{Array{Float64,1}},GLM.DensePredChol{Float64,Base.LinAlg.Cholesky{Float64,Array{Float64,2}}}},Array{Float64,2}}

Formula: Price ~ 1 + LotSize

Coefficients:
             Estimate Std.Error t value Pr(>|t|)
(Intercept)   6.46853  0.276741  23.374   <1e-83
LotSize      0.542179 0.0326501 16.6057   <1e-49
```

As a side note - application of `log` function to a vector is deprecated, you should use `log.` (broadcasted):

```
log_housing = DataFrame(LotSize=log.(housing[:,2]), Price=log.(housing[:,1]))
```